# Android Studio, CMake. How to print debug message in compile time?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 beta 3. I put `message(AUTHOR_WARNING "Hello CMake, hello Android")` In my CMakeLists.txt

But I saw this message only few times when rebuilding project in Android Studio. In most cases there's no `"Hello CMake, hello Android"` string in Gradle Console after build finishes. I've tried resync gradle and clean/rebuild project, still no expected output.

I have some problems with my build (I think it's incorrect paths) so my goal - to print CMake variables in compile time to better understand what is actually going on.

Comment: `CMake` messages are only a generation time (when `CMake` is used to generate your project). With that said I don't have experience with android studio.

Comment: Ok, `CMake` must generate `Makefile`, but in project tree I can't see any `Makefile` too.

Comment: Those are in the build directory.

Comment: From the build directory in a shell / cmd window you should be able to do a `cmake .` to get CMake to generate. There should be a `CMakeCache.txt` file in this folder.

Comment: Thank you! It's all I need! Post you comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CMake` messages are only at generation time (when `CMake` is used to generate your project / Makefile).

One way to get `CMake` to generate is to go to retrieve the build folder and the `CMakeCache.txt` file in it, and then:

1. Retrieve the path to your cmake executable, by reading the `CMakeCache.txt` file and checking the value of the `CMAKE_COMMAND` variable
2. Open a command prompt in `CMakeCache.txt` directory
3. Run:    `<path_to_cmake_found_at_point_1> .`

Note: The build folder should have a `CMakeCache.txt` file. The above will not work unless it does.

Comment: I believe that by doing this, CMake will use the (default) compiler of your system, and not the one used to cross-compile sources for Android (Clang).

Comment: The key here is the `CMakeCache.txt` file would have your previous configuration settings so it would not switch compilers.

Comment: @NormanPellet I fixed the answer, the underlying idea was very good.

Answer (score 35):

Inside the project tree, you can find the log with all the cmake output inside the folder of each generated architecture. The relative path to the file should be something like:

```
[project folder]/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/cmake_build_output.txt
```

Here you can see all the MESSAGE calls of the cmake scripts.

Comment: I can find this file, but my message isn't in it.

Comment: Make sure that your MESSAGE call is reached. Put a tests MESSAGE in the beginning of the CMakeList.txt script and see if it is in the log file. Clear the cache before the test.

Comment: I can't find the file (Android Studio 3.2.1 on Windows 10). There are CMakeCache.txt and /CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log but neither contain the CMake output

Comment: I use linux for development and don't really know Windows specific issues. However, sometimes the CMake script fails to early and the output is not generated yet. Try to simplify your script until all the elements are obviously correct (even the app will not work) and try to print a message. This is my suggestion.

Comment: For anyone else "app" is not meant literally.

Comment: for me it was on `appname/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/build_output.txt` but it didn't contain CMake message output.

Answer (score 10):

my android studio cmake output:

compile detail:

```
.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/compile_commands.json
```

cmake output:

```
.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/build_output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

On my rig I found the logs in <module name>/build/intermediates/cxx/<cmake build type>/<hash>/meta/<ABI>/cmake_server_log.txt -- C++ programming for Android just keeps getting more convenient all the time :\

My rig:

- Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3
- AGP 7.0.2
- Gradle 7.2.0
- NDK 21.4.7075529
- CMake 3.10.2
- Windows 10 (hopefully host OS doesn't matter)